# Make summing power series more efficient

Tags: python-2.7, math, modulus

I am coding in hackerrank and came across this problem: 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/power-calculation

My code works for small files and big numbers. As for the big files, it times out. Could someone make it more efficient.

My code:

```
 z = []
def modexp(a, n, m):
    bits = []
    while n:
        bits.append(n%2)
        n /= 2
    solution = 1
    bits.reverse()
    for x in bits:
        solution = (solution*solution)%m
        if x:
            solution = (solution*a)%m
    return solution


for _ in xrange(int(input())): 
    while True: 
            try:
                    x = raw_input()
                    sum =0
                    z = x.split(' ')
                    power = int(z[1])
                    limit = int(z[0])
                    for i in range(0,limit+1): 
                        sum = sum%100 + modexp(i%100,power, pow(10,2))
                    if sum < 10: 
                        print '%02d' % sum 
                    if sum > 10: 
                        print sum%100 
            except: 
                break
```

Sample data - input:

```
10
487348 808701
204397 738749
814036 784709
713222 692670
890568 452450
686541 933150
935447 202322
559883 847002
468195 111274
833627 238704
```

Sample output:

```
76
13
76
75
24
51
20
54
90
42
```

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be *your* exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can easily reduce the number of power evaluations by observing that its values mod 100 have a period of 100. Thus
decompose `K = M*100+L` by computing `M=K/100; L=K%100;`.

Then

- for `k=0` to `L` the power `modexp(k%100,N,100)` occurs `M+1` times,
- for `k=L+1` to `99` it occurs `M` times in the sum.

Thus each power sum can be reduced to 99 power computations

---

One can reduce the effort to compute the powers even more by observing that increasing powers of the same number are periodic in the last two digits. Generally the sequence

```
1, a % m, a**2 % m, a**3 % m, a**4 % m, ...
```

becomes periodic after some point that is given by the highest multiplicity of a prime factor. One period length is given by the value of `m` in Euler's totient function.

The totient value of `100=2²·5²` is `phi(100)=(2-1)·2·(5-1)·5=40`. The offset before the period sets in is at most 2, it follows that for all integers `a`

```
a**2 % 100 == a**42 % 100 = a**82 % 100 = ...
a**3 % 100 == a**43 % 100 = a**83 % 100 = ...
```

and so on.

Which means that for `N>41` one can reduce the exponent to `N=2+(N-2) % 40`. (Indeed one can replace `40` by `20` in that reduction.)

---

And as a final remark that will not have much impact on running times, only on the complexity of the code:

There is a shorter way to implement `modexp`, this algorithm is also a standard exercise to identify loop invariants:

```
def modexp(a, n, m):
    solution = 1
    apower = a
    while n:
        if (n%2): solution = (solution*apower) % m
        n /= 2
        apower = (apower*apower) % m
    return solution
```

Comment: could you explain the arthimetics better please cause I am confused.